# Can't losetup anything on armhf NAS

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, chroot, loop-device

I'm pretty new to linux and chrooted my NAS with `armhf` architecture and tried looping device:

```
losetup -f
losetup: Could not find any loop device. Maybe this kernel does not know
   about the loop device? (If so, recompile or `modprobe loop'.)
```

The result is what you can see. modprobe doesn't give anything, because loop isn't module and is a part of kernel (I think, after searching through net).

So is that because of armhf or there is some other gotchas?

My kernel version is 3.2.26.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the kernel includes support for loop devices, but that the entries in `/dev` are missing. Check for `loop?` entries in `/sys/class/block`. If they're absent, your kernel lacks the loop device driver. If they're present, and `/dev` is static, then you can create the missing entries with `MAKEDEV loop` (if available) or with

```
for i in `seq 0 15`; do mknod loop$i b 7 $i; done
```

If `/dev` is populated by udev, `/etc/udev/links.conf` should contain a line like

```
M loop0            b   7 0
```

If you have access to the kernel configuration (sometimes available as `/proc/config.gz`, or as a file called `config-…` somewhere like `/boot), check that it includes`CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP`set to`y`(built-in) or`m`(module). The module is`loop.ko`.

Comment: Well, there was `loop0` in the `/dev` from the start, and there aren't any `loop` devices. And there is `M loop0         b   7 0` inside `/etc/udev/links.conf`. So that means I can't create my own loop device?

Comment: @Dezl This indicates that udev is configured to create loop devices if the kernel supports them. But the kernel support is missing. You could create the device entries manually, but that wouldn't help, since accessing them would try to access a non-existent driver and thus always return an error (“no such device”).

Comment: So that means I can't use them? Is there any alternative to loop? Or I have to try to upgrade my kernel (I'd like not to do it, because I'm afraid I'll brickify my device in that case).

Comment: Or there is a way to attach some driver to support it? Actually I want to try to use `tcplay` - it's the only alternative to `TrueCrypt`, that successfully compiled on my `armhf`-drived system.

Comment: @Dezl Doesn't your NAS support dmcrypt? You could compile the loop module independently, but you need to have the kernel configuration.

Comment: Well I'm really new to linux, so I still don't know any good software. So I tried first thing I came up with. I'll try dm-crypt, as you suggested. But do I still need some device like loop for it? BTW, [tcplay](https://github.com/bwalex/tc-play), that I mentioned earlier, is based on dm-crypt.